# Cannot insert values into localDB because of too long identifier

Tags: localdb

I am using visual studio 2015 to create a localdb project. I want to store web page information including : PageID, Name, Title, Description, and PublicFacing.

Here is what my table looks like
[image: DB Design]

And here is my insert statement

```
insert into dbo.Page(Name, Title, Description, PublicFacing) VALUES ("index", "My Website | Wholesale Prices", "Wholesale Prices, Products, Items, Gadget service provider.  Delivering a management platform to ITSPs and resellers. You can get it all here", 1);
```

When I try to run this statement, I get the following error :

```
The identifier that starts with 'Wholesale Prices, Products, Items, Gadget service provider.  Delivering a management platform to ITSPs and resellers. You can get it all here' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

I guess why I'm confused is, I dont know why it's calling this the identifier. This is the value going into my database, and it is under the max varchar limit I set in the table. What is causing this?

Comment: Is is mysql or  SQL Server localdb?

Comment: SQL Server localDB. mysql tag removed.

Comment: Description is max 170 chars!

Comment: The description I'm supplying 141 characters.

Comment: Use single quotes around your text values

Comment: @ErikEJ That was it. Feel pretty dumb right about now. If you put that in the form of an answer I'll be happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes around your text values!